# Jenkins Pipeline steps that run before Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkinsfile

I'm just starting to get my toes wet with Jenkins and CI/CD.

I've built a set of static analysis tools and corresponding configurations I want to run before a branch's Jenkinsfile is even considered. I want to have Jenkins run these tools across every branch regardless of what the Jenkinsfile on the branch says. I want to make sure that the static analysis is out of the purview of the repo. How can I build a set of steps that are run before the Jenkinsfile on the branch is considered?

Answer (score 1):

I see (at least) two possible solutions that both have their drawbacks.

1. Using a shared library containing all the code for your static analysis. That code can then be called as a step in the pipeline.  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/. This doesn't keep the execution out of the pipeline completely, but it keeps the code out of each pipeline/branch and is (in my opinion) a pretty straight forward solution.
2. Putting the static analysis into a separate job, trigger that job for example with a git hook and then let that job trigger the pipeline. I my opinion a more complex solution that has more moving parts, but may be closer to what you're asking for.